# Use VBA to insert a formula in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that should fill 8 rows with a formula

```
Sub df_opbouwen()

  num_weeks = 8 + 10

  For i = 10 To num_weeks

     Sheets("Blad1").Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=WEEKNUMMER(D10)"

  Next i

End Sub
```

However, when I open the Excel, I still get a `#name?` error. That's strange because when I just enter `=WEEKNUMMER(D10)` in the cell it does work.

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: I am curious what happens if you write it R1C1 style (which will shorten your code and avoid a loop:  `With Sheets("Blad1") | .Range(.Cells(10,2),.Cells(18,2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKNUMMER(RC[2])" | End With`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman this assumes that OP wants the formulas _not_ to all point at cell D10, but if that is the intention then this is a good solution

Comment: VBA is very English centric. Either out the English version of the formula or use `.Formulalocal`

Comment: @Frits Verstraten what are you trying to achieve ? what do you want in column B from row 10 to 18 ? do you want to have the week number of D10 in all of them ? or to loop down all the way to D18 ?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks, when I try to run it I get a compile errror (not valid or qualified reference) however. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ScottCraner, it works. Thanks!\

Comment: assuming you took the pipes out (they represented line breaks) - you can ignore my comment as @ScottCraner hit the nail on the head :)

Answer (score 0):

you have a small type error:

```
Sub df_opbouwen()

num_weeks = 8 + 10

For i = 10 To num_weeks
    Sheets("Blad1").Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=WEEKNUM(D10)"
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: perhaps not - see [WEEKNUMMER](https://support.office.com/nl-nl/article/WEEKNUMMER-functie-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340)

Comment: But OP is intending to use the "WeekNummer" function (as stated in the question)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman The page uses Germain and when I translate to English, it's translated as WEEKNUM

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 - scottcraner hit the nail on the head in the comment to the original post, I think